# How to use purrr::map and aov functions inside a function and pass the function arguments into the aov?

Tags: r, parameter-passing, purrr, anova

I'm trying to create a function to generalize this **working** line: `aov_res <- map(my_data[metals_list], ~tryCatch(aov(. ~ my_x * my_z, data = my_data), error = function(e) NULL))` with `df` is a dataframe and `metals_list` is a list of Y variables for the ANOVA test.

Inside a more general function. somthing like that:

```
anova_fun <- function(df,x.var,z.var){
  aov_res <- map(df[metals_list], ~tryCatch(aov(. ~ x.var * z.var, data = df), error = function(e) NULL))
}
anova_fun(my_data,my_x,my_z)
```

for some reason, the function version **creates a list of empty lists**, with 11 warning, one for each metal in the `metals_list`:

```
Warning: restarting interrupted promise evaluationWarning: restarting interrupted promise evaluationWarning: restarting interrupted promise evaluationWarning: restarting interrupted promise evaluationWarning: restarting interrupted promise evaluationWarning: restarting interrupted promise evaluationWarning: restarting interrupted promise evaluationWarning: restarting interrupted promise evaluationWarning: restarting interrupted promise evaluationWarning: restarting interrupted promise evaluationWarning: restarting interrupted promise evaluation
```

Comment: what is `df`? is it a dataframe or a list of dataframes? what is `metals_list`??

Comment: `df` is a dataframe and `metals_list` is a list of Y variables for the ANOVA test. I edited it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing `map`. In your case, the first argument of `map` shouldn't be a dataframe with y variable, but rather the y variable name.

### Solution

Here is a solution to your problem, demonstrated with `mtcars`, where the y-variables are `mpg`, `drat`, and `wt` (three anova models), and the x and z variables are `disp` and `vs` respectively.

```
# Reading required libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)

# prep work
df <- mtcars
y_vars <- c("mpg", "drat", "wt") # this is what you call `metals_list`
x_var <- "disp" # your x-variable
z_var <- "vs" # your z-variable

# a basic function that has variable names, as strings, for input
create_aov <- function(y_var, x_var, z_var) {
  aov(formula = as.formula(glue("{y_var} ~ {x_var}*{z_var}")),
      data = df)
}

# A safe version of the function (alternative to `tryCatch`)
safe_aov <- possibly(create_aov)

# A complete run of the function
final_res <- map(y_vars, ~safe_aov(., x_var, z_var))

# extract first result using
# final_res[[1]]$result
```

### Output

Output when printing `final_res`:

```
[[1]]
Call:
   aov(formula = as.formula(glue("{y_var} ~ {x_var}*{z_var}")),
    data = df)

Terms:
                    disp       vs  disp:vs Residuals
Sum of Squares  808.8885   8.7179  61.5273  246.9135
Deg. of Freedom        1        1        1        28

Residual standard error: 2.969569
Estimated effects may be unbalanced

[[2]]
Call:
   aov(formula = as.formula(glue("{y_var} ~ {x_var}*{z_var}")),
    data = df)

Terms:
                    disp       vs  disp:vs Residuals
Sum of Squares  4.470189 0.073905 0.698982  3.619246
Deg. of Freedom        1        1        1        28

Residual standard error: 0.3595258
Estimated effects may be unbalanced

[[3]]
Call:
   aov(formula = as.formula(glue("{y_var} ~ {x_var}*{z_var}")),
    data = df)

Terms:
                     disp        vs   disp:vs Residuals
Sum of Squares  23.401940  0.345362  0.316624  5.614822
Deg. of Freedom         1         1         1        28

Residual standard error: 0.4478051
Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```

### Comments

#### Improvement #1

In the function, you can extract a tidy outcome if you use `broom::tidy` like this:

```
create_aov <- function(y_var, x_var, z_var) {
  aov(formula = as.formula(glue("{y_var} ~ {x_var}*{z_var}")),
      data = df) |>
    broom::tidy()
}
```

#### Improvement #2

Replace `possibly` with `safely` if you want a different arrangement of error messages (should they occur).

#### Important! About asking questions in StackOverflow

Your question could have been improved (**and probably answered faster**) if you had provided a minimum example (e.g., using `mtcars` like I did), and an example of the desired output.

Comment: Thank u @Adi Sarid ! I think i am missing something, I'm still having trouble generalizing your solution using a function and passing `x_var` and  `z_var` as variables into the `final__res` , otherwise I have to type this row many times: `final_res <- map(y_vars, ~safe_aov(., x_var, z_var))`. Am I right?
Also, if u can help me understand: y is it that the same code (`aov_res <- map(my_data[metals_list], ~tryCatch(aov(. ~ my_x * my_z, data = my_data), error = function(e) NULL))`) works outside the function if the problem is with the way I`m using `map`?
Thank u again